# Can't get aws alarms by its MetricName (returns empty array) using AWS SDK

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk, amazon-cloudwatch

I need to get all alarms by its MetricName (StatusCheckFailed). My code is:

```
var aws = require('aws-sdk');

var cw = new aws.CloudWatch();

var params = {
    MetricName: 'StatusCheckFailed',
    Namespace: 'AWS/EC2'
};

cw.describeAlarmsForMetric(params, function(err, data){
    if (err){
        console.log(err, err.stack);
        return;
    }

    console.log(data);
});
```

The result is:

```
{ ResponseMetadata: { RequestId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' }, MetricAlarms: [] }
```

Since I have alarms with this MetricName in my account, why MetricAlarms is empty? Am I missing any parameter? How can I fix it?